# ReactJS: Combine same items in array

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to loop through items in an array and combine ingredients (for example with the array below I have Cheese in a few meals - I would like to only show Cheese once and sum the quantity of each)

I define my const as:

```
const categorizedDataFoods12 = listUserM.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { id, Category, Foods } = curr;
    if (!acc[Category]) {
      acc[Category] = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    acc[Category].items.push({ id, Category, Foods });
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

And then loop through these using:

```
{categorizedDataFoods12[key]?.items
    .map((checkbox, index) => {
    const data4food = checkbox.Foods
    const d4f = data4food.map((d) =>
```

While this works, it shows cheese multiple times. How do I if an ingredient appears multiple times, just show it the once in my list?

My array:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "biuBOoxw8Jxn9PPmyBKu",
            "Category": "LUNCH",
            "Foods": [
                {
                    "value": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
                    "label": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
                    "id": "ynBBDaX807LUa0093fJm",
                    "Weight": "0.312",
                    "Quantity": "0.50"
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "value": "Coppa (200g)",
                    "Weight": "0.200",
                    "id": "meyqfO8dxmNrx19EV86o",
                    "label": "Coppa (200g)"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Weight": 0.25,
                    "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
                },
                {
                    "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Weight": 0.28
                },
                {
                    "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "Weight": 0.17
                },
                {
                    "value": "Pickled Onions",
                    "id": "qSiC2ZR8v976QBzd0HTh",
                    "Quantity": "3.00",
                    "label": "Pickled Onions",
                    "Weight": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "PodfQqRU3UOFKq4QX26q",
            "Category": "LUNCH",
            "Foods": [
                {
                    "id": "ynBBDaX807LUa0093fJm",
                    "value": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
                    "Weight": "0.312",
                    "label": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
                    "Quantity": "0.50"
                },
                {
                    "Weight": 0.25,
                    "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "Weight": 0.28,
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)"
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "Weight": 0.17,
                    "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Pickled Onions",
                    "Weight": "",
                    "id": "qSiC2ZR8v976QBzd0HTh",
                    "value": "Pickled Onions",
                    "Quantity": "3.00"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "ukZv9L19IHwIk4QRs0Aq",
            "Category": "LUNCH",
            "Foods": [
                {
                    "value": "Ham",
                    "Weight": 0.176,
                    "label": "Ham",
                    "Quantity": "1.00"
                },
                {
                    "Weight": 0.59,
                    "id": "76fd7a60-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "label": "Wraps (8 pack)",
                    "Quantity": "0.25",
                    "value": "Wraps (8 pack)"
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
                    "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Weight": 0.25,
                    "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Weight": 0.17,
                    "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "Quantity": 1
                },
                {
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "Weight": 0.28,
                    "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "BGS8QUqy8bMoTgA61bgf",
            "Category": "LUNCH",
            "Foods": [
                {
                    "label": "Wraps (8 pack)",
                    "value": "Wraps (8 pack)",
                    "Quantity": "0.30",
                    "id": "76fd7a60-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Food": "",
                    "Weight": 0.59
                },
                {
                    "value": "Coppa (200g)",
                    "Weight": "0.200",
                    "Quantity": "0.25",
                    "label": "Coppa (200g)",
                    "id": "meyqfO8dxmNrx19EV86o"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
                    "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
                    "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Weight": 0.25,
                    "Quantity": "0.50"
                },
                {
                    "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Quantity": "0.50",
                    "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
                    "Weight": 0.28
                },
                {
                    "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
                    "Quantity": 1,
                    "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
                    "Weight": 0.17,
                    "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Difficult to understand what is the expected result, would be best if you just provide the expected array.

Answer (score 0):

For each item, you can start an outer reducer of type `Map`. And for each item of `Foods`, you can reduce them onto the `outer` map (which is internally called `inner`. Check the map for an existing key of by the current item's `value`. Sum the `Weight` and `Quantity` against the existing item. Now, replace the existing (modified) value. We ignore the `id` of each item, because it does not matter when the data is reduced.

Once you have the map, spread (`[...]`) the `values()` and `sort` by the `value` (or `label`).

**Note:** It looks like `label` and `value` are always the same. You will also noticed that the `Weight` and `Quantity` are casted to a number using the `+` prefix. This prevents accidental string concatenation.

```js
const data = [...fetchData().items.reduce((outer, { Foods }) => Foods
  .reduce((inner, { id, value, label, Weight, Quantity }) => {
    let existing = inner.get(value) ?? { value, label, Weight: 0, Quantity: 0 };
    existing.Weight += +Weight;
    existing.Quantity += +Quantity;
    return inner.set(value, existing);
  }, outer), new Map).values()]
  .sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));

console.log(data);

function fetchData() {
  return {
    "items": [{
      "id": "biuBOoxw8Jxn9PPmyBKu",
      "Category": "LUNCH",
      "Foods": [{
        "value": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
        "label": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
        "id": "ynBBDaX807LUa0093fJm",
        "Weight": "0.312",
        "Quantity": "0.50"
      }, {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Coppa (200g)",
        "Weight": "0.200",
        "id": "meyqfO8dxmNrx19EV86o",
        "label": "Coppa (200g)"
      }, {
        "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Weight": 0.25,
        "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
      }, {
        "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Weight": 0.28
      }, {
        "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "Weight": 0.17
      }, {
        "value": "Pickled Onions",
        "id": "qSiC2ZR8v976QBzd0HTh",
        "Quantity": "3.00",
        "label": "Pickled Onions",
        "Weight": ""
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "PodfQqRU3UOFKq4QX26q",
      "Category": "LUNCH",
      "Foods": [{
        "id": "ynBBDaX807LUa0093fJm",
        "value": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
        "Weight": "0.312",
        "label": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
        "Quantity": "0.50"
      }, {
        "Weight": 0.25,
        "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
      }, {
        "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "Weight": 0.28,
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)"
      }, {
        "Quantity": 1,
        "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "Weight": 0.17,
        "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers"
      }, {
        "label": "Pickled Onions",
        "Weight": "",
        "id": "qSiC2ZR8v976QBzd0HTh",
        "value": "Pickled Onions",
        "Quantity": "3.00"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "ukZv9L19IHwIk4QRs0Aq",
      "Category": "LUNCH",
      "Foods": [{
        "value": "Ham",
        "Weight": 0.176,
        "label": "Ham",
        "Quantity": "1.00"
      }, {
        "Weight": 0.59,
        "id": "76fd7a60-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "label": "Wraps (8 pack)",
        "Quantity": "0.25",
        "value": "Wraps (8 pack)"
      }, {
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
        "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Weight": 0.25,
        "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)"
      }, {
        "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Weight": 0.17,
        "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "Quantity": 1
      }, {
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "Weight": 0.28,
        "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)"
      }]
    }, {
      "id": "BGS8QUqy8bMoTgA61bgf",
      "Category": "LUNCH",
      "Foods": [{
        "label": "Wraps (8 pack)",
        "value": "Wraps (8 pack)",
        "Quantity": "0.30",
        "id": "76fd7a60-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Food": "",
        "Weight": 0.59
      }, {
        "value": "Coppa (200g)",
        "Weight": "0.200",
        "Quantity": "0.25",
        "label": "Coppa (200g)",
        "id": "meyqfO8dxmNrx19EV86o"
      }, {
        "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
        "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
        "id": "74b67090-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Weight": 0.25,
        "Quantity": "0.50"
      }, {
        "id": "74c64f10-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Quantity": "0.50",
        "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
        "Weight": 0.28
      }, {
        "id": "74d5df70-15da-11ec-b278-b1ac8c1941a3",
        "Quantity": 1,
        "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
        "Weight": 0.17,
        "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers"
      }]
    }]
  };
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```json
[
  {
    "value": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
    "label": "Cheddar Cheese (250g)",
    "Weight": 1,
    "Quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
    "label": "Cherry Tomatoes (punnet)",
    "Weight": 1.12,
    "Quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "value": "Coppa (200g)",
    "label": "Coppa (200g)",
    "Weight": 0.4,
    "Quantity": 1.25
  },
  {
    "value": "Ham",
    "label": "Ham",
    "Weight": 0.176,
    "Quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "value": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
    "label": "Lebanese Cucumbers",
    "Weight": 0.68,
    "Quantity": 4
  },
  {
    "value": "Pickled Onions",
    "label": "Pickled Onions",
    "Weight": 0,
    "Quantity": 6
  },
  {
    "value": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
    "label": "Vita-Weat (pack)",
    "Weight": 0.624,
    "Quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "value": "Wraps (8 pack)",
    "label": "Wraps (8 pack)",
    "Weight": 1.18,
    "Quantity": 0.55
  }
]
```